# script to toggle between at least three commands

Tags: bash, scripting

How do I write a bash script that, when called with a key binding, will toggle between various commands (e.g., the 4 distinct commands shown below).

The script should remember which command it stopped on last time it  was called and be able to toggle between at least three commands.

For example, I want to toggle between four screen wall papers using `feh` as shown below, how would I do this ?

```
feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20150620_182419_1.jpg
feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20150620_182419_2.jpg
feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20150620_182419_3.jpg
feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20150620_182419_4.jpg
```

Comment: What have you tried? And where are you stuck?

Comment: no knowledge on this one. I can toggle between two commands using a if then else statement that looks at and creates a file (file exists or does not exist dependant on toggle status). What you see above is what i've got, thats it. Fairly extensive googling has revealed nothing I can find.

Comment: So you want a loop? User get a list of 4 items and a question to select one. If for example 2 is selected, then do something with 2, then show a list of 1, 3 and 4. If now, 3 is selected execute and show list of 1 and 4. etc? Or do you have say 100 items. You want to list 4 of 100. Next round list 4 of 99 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want the same command to produce different output each time it's called, such that you cycle sequentially over the four different files.

To do this you need to maintain state, so you know what is required on the next call. In my example I'll save the index number (0..3) of the current wallpaper. When the index number reaches the number of available files it's reset to zero using the modulo (`%`) operator.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
files=(20150620_182419_1.jpg 20150620_182419_2.jpg 20150620_182419_3.jpg 20150620_182419_4.jpg)
dir_photos="$HOME/Pictures"          # Directory of photos
state="$HOME/.${0##*/}.dat"          # File to maintain state

index=$(cat "$state" 2>/dev/null)    # Retrieve last index
nFiles=${#files[@]}                  # Number of entries in files()

# Set current index to zero if first time, otherwise next value in sequence
[[ -z "$index" ]] && index=0 || index=$((++index % nFiles))

printf "%d\n" $index >"$state"       # Save new index
# echo "State index=$index: ${files[index]}"

# Apply the wallpaper
feh --bg-scale "$dir_photos/${files[index]}"
```

Save this as a file and make it executable. Then bind your key to call this script.

You could modify it to iterate across all files in the `$dir_photos` directory:

```
dir_photos="$HOME/Pictures"          # Directory of photos
files=("$dir_photos"/*)              # All files in the directory
...
feh --bg-scale "${files[index]}"
```

Comment: thanks, thats a very nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I suppose I could run this small loop in the background and connect each option to a hot key which was my original intention, but I don't know how to connect to a background process via a hot key.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set an infinite loop until option is set and quit

while :
do
    clear
    
    # display menu
    echo "  --------------------------------------------------"
    echo "     W A L L P A P E R   C H A N G E R - M E N U"
    echo "  --------------------------------------------------"
    echo
    echo "  1   wall paper 1"
    echo
    echo "  2   edit wall paper 1"
    echo
    echo "  3   wall paper 2"
    echo
    echo "  4   wall paper 3"
    echo
    echo "  5   wall paper changer - does not work yet"
    echo
    echo "  6   this script: pcmanfm to dir location"
    echo
    echo "  7   this script: edit this script"
    echo
    echo "  8   display network connections"
    echo
    echo "  q   exit"
    echo
    echo

    # set-up reference directories

    dir_z="/home/$USER/Dropbox/script_screen_SAVER_feh"
    dir_photos="/home/$USER/wall_papers"

    # get input from the user 
    read -p "  enter your choice [ 1 - 7  or   q/Q ] " choice
        
    # make decision using case..in..esac 
    case $choice in
        1)
            feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20210620_182419_3.jpg
            echo "wall paper 1"
            exit 0
            ;;
        2)
            gimp $dir_photos/20210620_182419_3.xcf
            echo "wall paper 1, edit image"
            ;;
        3) 
            feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20210620_182419_1.jpg
            echo "Quotes"
            exit 0
            ;;
        4) 
            feh --bg-scale $dir_photos/20210621_135308.jpg
            echo "The sea - wall paper"
            exit 0
            ;;
        5)
            # kill previously running wallpaper changer process
            ps aux | grep "feh/" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15
            # change the wallpaper every 5 seconds
            bash -c 'while : ;do feh --randomize --bg-fill --auto-rotate $dir_photos/*.jpg; sleep 5; done' &
            disown
            echo "wall paper changer"
            exit 0
            ;;
        6) 
            pcmanfm $dir_photos
            echo "pcmanfm directory"
            ;;
        7) 
                        nvim $dir_z/more_than_3_screens_switcher.sh
            echo "editing this script"
            ;;
        8)
            netstat -nat
            read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..." readEnterKey
            ;;
        q)
            echo "Bye!"
            exit 0
            ;;
        Q)
            echo "Bye!"
            exit 0
            ;;      *)
            echo "Error: Invalid option..." 
            ;;


    esac        
                
done
```